# Data about completed prison term by country

Tags: data-request, releasing-data, crime, global

I'm looking data *(preferentially free and open data but I can afford small payments)* by country worldwide on the percent of population **that have completed a prison sentence or were sentenced**.

I only found statistics about people who actually are in jail.

Comment: Are you interested in one or more particular countries?

Comment: Interested worldwide size.

Answer (score 3):

The Indian Government provides year-wise statistics on the number of people who are in prison and percentage of prison population by sentence length. So you could calculate the population which has completed its sentences. The data is available from: http://www.ncrb.gov.in/prisonstatisticarchieve/Main.htm